# Why does identical SwiftUI code work on iOS and fail on macOS?

Tags: macos, validation, swiftui, textfield

I’ve built a simple SwiftUI app using the Multiplatform template. It compiles for iOS and macOS without errors or warnings. All the code is in the shared files, I’ve added nothing specific for iOS or macOS.

It runs correctly on iPhone and iPad simulators. It also **seems** to run on macOS, producing the interface I’m expecting but **it is not working** under the hood. No crashes, just incorrect behaviour. All that’s expected to happen is that the user enters data into TextFields and it is validated and added to UserDefaults. In the iOS version, invalid data is rejected (field reverts to default value) and valid data is stored in UserDefaults, exactly as expected. In the macOS version (identical code) all input is rejected (field reverts to default value).

Any thoughts? Is something extra required before SwiftUI works on macOS?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Was just working on one and I've cracked the problem and found an Apple bug!! Will add it to my question and close it.

Answer (score 1):

Working on an example, I discovered the solution.

Here's what I found out:

On iOS, when a field gets focus it emits **onEditingChanged(true)** and when it loses focus without a commit (i.e.) it emits **onEditingChanged(false)**;  when it loses it with a commit it emits **onCommit()** and then it emits **onEditingChanged(false)**. IMHO, these last two are not in the correct logical order. I think you stop editing and only then do you commit.

On macOS, when a field gets focus it remains silent but once you type anything, it emits **onEditingChanged(true)**; when it loses focus with or without a commit it emits **onEditingChanged(false)** followed by **onCommit()**. IMHO, these arrive in the correct logical order but we cannot distinguish between committing and abandoning the editing.

Can anybody suggest how to distinguish these cases?